# Why am I shown this "unauthorized" prior to every login on my AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

Each time I try to log in to my AWS account, I get this 'unauthorized' page. When I click the 'sign in again', it logs in fine like it should have done the first time. I am using firefox auto-fill for my password/username, and a yubi-key for 2FA.
[image]

Comment: Is this still an issue you're getting? I'm having the same issue but can't find any documentation around it. I'm worried that we might have some IAM misconfigurations as our users are deployed using terraform, so something might be missing.

Comment: @DanielPerez I'm no longer experiencing the issue, but not sure why. Nothing has changed really.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue happening. So far, no clue as to why.

Comment: @AntonioCS are you using a hardware key for MFA by any chance?

Comment: @Schquestoning MFA on the root a account which is not the account I'm using to login

Comment: FYI: I am also facing the same issue as well(Feb 2024 tried login via Firefox/chrome), unable to find any solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found that I had created a link to go to the console in a personal homepage. The link contained more than just the path, which was no longer valid.

The solution for me was to log in and go to **Security credentials** under the account dropdown menu on the right.

Under the **Console sign-in** section, copy the link and use the link to get to the login page for future site visits.